# How to rearrange data from a vector (list) into a matrix (table) in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector

Given three `K` by 1 arrays `date`, `ticker`, and `volume` containing information about financial transactions, I would like to compute a `T` by `N` array containing the same information in a more accessible format. My vectors look like this:

```
ticker    date    volume
______    ____    ______
'ABCD'    735602  123456
'ABCD'    735603  789101
'FGHI'    735602  112131
'NOPQ'    735602  415161
'NOPQ'    735603  718192
'NOPQ'    735605  021232
...       ...     ...
```

The matrix I want to obtain would look like this (shown as a table for illustration):

```
         'ABCD'  'FGHI'  'JKLM'  'NOPQ'  ...
         ______  ______  ______  ______
735602 | 123456  112131  000000  415161
735603 | 789101  000000  000000  718192
735604 | 000000  000000  000000  000000
735605 | 000000  000000  000000  021232
...
735963
```

Note that the dimensions of my matrix are pre-specified and they do not depend on the size of any of my input vectors because not all tickers are contained in my input vectors; similarly, not all dates are represented in my input vectors. All coefficients of the matrix whose volume value is not contained in the input vectors should be set to `0`.

I have been experimenting with loops and conditions to the point where I have gotten quite confused. I am sure for someone with a more advanced knowledge this is a rather basic task. Any suggestions on how to approach this are greatly appreciated!

This question is related to [this previous one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761613/how-to-use-matlab-to-consolidate-financial-transactions-combination-of-duplicat). Thanks to the solution found for this question, each entry in `volume` can be identified unambiguously by the corresponding `ticker` and `date` so this is no longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to convert the `'ticker'` string to a numeris index into the table.
You can do that using [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html)

```
[~,~,tIdx] = unique( ticker );
```

Now you can use [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to accumulate the `volume` information into a 2D table

```
myTable = accumarray( {date, tIdx}, volume, [T N] );
```

Alternatively, if the entries to `myTable` are unique and do not require accumulation, you can use `sub2ind`:

```
myTable = zeros( T, N );
myTable( sub2ind([T,N], date, tIdx) ) = volume;
```

Another option (if the range of `date` is too large) is to save `myTable` as [sparse](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/sparse-matrices.html) matrix

```
myTable = sparse( date, tIdx, volume );
```

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion.Unfortunately I get the error message `First input SUBS and third input SZ must satisfy ALL(MAX(SUBS)<=SZ)`. My `K = 620`; my `T = 252`; my `N = 211`. This seems to be because the index `tIdx` exceeds the dimensions of `SZ`. How can this be fixed?

Comment: if your `N` is 211 it means you have at most 211 unique `'ticker'` values, if this assumption does not hold - you'll need to change the code. Try running `accumarray` without the last argument `[T N]` and see what is the size of the resulting `myTable`.

Comment: The number of unique tickers is far below 211. There must be something wrong with the syntax. `size(myTable,1)` when running without the last option is above 700,000.

Comment: The size of the resulting array in the second dimension is interestingly correct at `170`.

Comment: @Constantin what are the typical values of `date`? is it running from 1 to 211?  or is it different than the values in your example? you might need to do the `unique` trick for the dates as well...

Comment: @Constantin BTW, if most of the entries in `myTable` are zeros, you might want to save it as `sparse`.

Comment: the entries in `date` are non-unique datenumbers. `size(unique(date),1) = 214 < 255`.

Comment: @Constantin but what is `max(date)`?

Comment: `max(date) = 735963`. Perhaps this is where my example was inappropriate by starting from `0001`. Do I need to create an index for my date numbers as well?

Comment: @Constantin it seems like it, `[~,~,dIdx] = unique(date);` then `accumarray( {dIdx,tIdx},volume,[T N] );`

Comment: this gets the data into the matrix, but in the wrong positions. In my example, the ticker `NOPQ` would have been given the index 3 and wrongly placed in the `JKLM` colums of the matrix.

Comment: The challenge is that I do not only know the dimensions of the target matrix already but also the `dates` and `tickers` which correspond to its entries. For illustration, imagine the target matrix represents all constituents of a large stock index over time. Each transaction in the initial vector pertains to a day and a ticker covered by the matrix, but the matrix also covers many other days and other tickers which are not contained in the input and which often lie between the `tickers` and `dates` where zeros should remain.

Comment: @Constantin if you already have a mapping between `date` and the corresponding index into `myTable` (and between `ticker` and `tIDx`) you should use this mapping.

Comment: Could you perhaps add this step to your answer? I am afraid my understanding of maps is not very good...

Comment: @Constantin - this mapping requires additional information that you seem to have and not present in the example. However, it seems like `date` has 214 unique values in the range 1..735963. For some reason you have a specific row in your table for each unique date value, you simply need to replace `dIdx` (the output of `unique`) with the entry you want. You can use a look up table or a `containers.Map` object to implement this mapping. same goes for the ticker indices.

Comment: Please excuse the ambiguity. My `min(date) = 735602` because these are serial date numbers counting from January 0, 0000. My attempt to make my example "minimal" unfortunately obscured this; I was simply assuming it would work the same way.

Comment: @Constantin please see my edit regarding `sparse`. Another option is to subtract `min(date)` from all dates to get `dIdx`:  `dIdx=date-min(date(:));`.

Comment: Again thank you, but I am afraid I do not sufficiently understand the `accumarray` function to construct this myself.

Comment: @Constantin `accumarray` can be tricky to master, but it's worth the trouble learning - it is a very useful and powerful function. I suggest you take the time to play with it, learn it and read it's documentation.

Comment: I do not understand how I can construct the indices based on both the `dates` from my input vector and the `dates` already specified for my output matrix; same problem with the tickers. This doesn't seem to be the main focus of what `accumarray` does. I understand now how accumarray can be used to construct *some non-redundant matrix* but in my specific case I am still a bit helpless.